# How to pass msg.value as an argument?

Tags: address.transfer

I am trying to implement deposit functionality in my contract in the sense whoever calls the function below needs to deposit some ether. For example:

Contract A calls the function below and again, Contract A needs to deposit some ether.

I can do this with the remix interface by passing "VALUE". But I want to pass this variable as an argument.

Here is what

```
event Deposit(address sender, uint amount, uint balance);

function deposit(uint testAmount) public payable {
    testAmount = msg.value; // GIVES ERROR
    emit Deposit(msg.sender, testAmount, address(this).balance);
} 

function doWork(int job_id, uint amount) public payable{
   deposit(amount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're trying to reassign to a parameter, which you don't need to do. This is likely the simplest change you could make to get this to work:

```
event Deposit(address sender, uint amount, uint balance);

function deposit() public payable {
    emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value, address(this).balance);
} 

function doWork(int job_id, uint amount) public payable{
   deposit();
}
```

Comment: This still requires passing the AMOUNT that I want to deposit to a smart contract using the VALUE input of the remix solidity. I am trying to not use the interface of remix.

Comment: @emrah I'm not sure what you mean by "interface of remix". The above seems to do what you want, taking the value from the msg.value field